# How can I obtain the raw decimal value of an RSA key's modulus?

Tags: rsa, keys

So maybe I'm thinking about this too hard, or maybe I'm missing a piece of information.

We'll use Google for this example. Say I wanted to obtain the modulus of Google's current public key.
Well I can do this relatively simply using OpenSSL:

> openssl s_client -connect www.google.com:443 | openssl x509 -text -pubkey

Great, so now I export that into a pem file. So now I have their certificate and their public key. Let's discard their certificate for this instance.
Also using OpenSSL, I can list the raw hexadecimal value of the modulus:

> openssl rsa -in pubKey.pem -pubin -text -noout

Now that lists this information:

`Public-Key: (2048 bit)
Modulus:
    00:c3:d5:12:42:8a:36:02:f5:77:01:8b:f6:83:2f:
    ab:c5:c7:00:e4:c0:3e:94:33:3a:2e:7a:2d:37:30:
    c0:6c:75:67:d4:13:d0:30:b1:11:34:16:21:6f:95:
    99:b0:f6:31:3c:55:51:b9:3f:8c:c3:63:50:b9:d0:
    03:7f:bb:76:53:66:80:4e:3e:51:d6:77:e6:5c:f5:
    38:b1:19:88:7b:86:f8:2d:39:d0:12:4c:d0:6a:5e:
    37:f1:bb:22:47:ec:d8:08:ca:06:81:44:4b:11:ef:
    51:aa:e6:96:b8:ad:ed:6b:15:be:01:4b:bc:60:c9:
    df:42:0a:df:d3:8b:e5:b0:03:ac:18:ef:c3:f8:3a:
    96:5e:a6:77:61:fe:36:1e:f5:f2:aa:83:1f:69:d4:
    79:5d:69:a9:d9:a1:18:a2:98:cd:e6:3d:5b:1e:0f:
    a9:66:c8:42:f2:ba:b0:74:e8:5f:b3:b5:30:6d:79:
    a9:e8:9f:9c:23:5f:51:aa:36:2e:35:a7:9a:08:76:
    f9:46:f0:34:de:70:1a:3d:4e:f7:34:68:e4:43:75:
    bf:20:58:54:66:1c:9f:6d:9b:9d:28:21:15:ae:89:
    a7:e9:6f:75:7e:22:49:93:85:c6:a4:c5:2b:1a:23:
    92:f9:eb:8f:67:a8:26:56:e1:9f:66:e5:74:2a:01:
    0c:17
Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)`

Great! I have the hexadecimally encoded modulus.
I've read many articles and have seen many websites that offer this, but, for future purposes, I'll just say that I don't necessarily prefer uploading keyfiles (public or private) to external services and "hoping" that they don't record it.

For experimental purposes, how might I obtain the plain decimal version of this modulus using a local client in Linux? I've seen a lot of posts showing that people have done it, but I'm having trouble figuring it out for whatever reason.

Also, I've heard a little bit about the prefixing "00" of this hexadecimal string (**00**:c3:d5:12:42...), about how it's just a bug. Can you give me more information on this, such as why it occurs and if it's relevant?

Comment: Actually, the prefix "00" is not a bug - instead, the tool is listing exactly what's in the ASN.1 (DER) of the public key, and for 2048 bit positive integers, the initial 0x00 is mandatory...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about converting numbers between different representations, rather than cryptographic theory. This should be asked on [Super User](https://superuser.com) or perhaps [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) instead.

Comment: Note that a publickey is already public so someone 'recording' it doesn't matter. You don't want to upload a privatekey, but for RSA the modulus in the privatekey and publickey are defined to be the same, so to get the modulus the privatekey isn't needed.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49850/does-bc-support-hex-calculations ... combine this with `sed` or `grep` and you should be golden.

Comment: Related: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/45151/anatomy-of-an-rsa-private-key

Answer (score 7):

You've downloaded Google's (or whomever's) certificate. You have it stored in a file called GoogleCert:

```
$ cat GoogleCert
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIIdDCCB1ygAwIBAgIIWOU4T7CaLpQwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwVDELMAkGA1UE
BhMCVVMxHjAcBgNVBAoTFUdvb2dsZSBUcnVzdCBTZXJ2aWNlczElMCMGA1UEAxMc
...
JmztPlaPUkFUEnAL2aWCAQCHscxb9bMFDmUW/kv/UnBNBBX7PRvl5rPjPeFk9yS5
HU2vHiQa8VY=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Use the command `openssl x509 -in FILENAME -noout -modulus` argument to extract just the Modulus:

```
$ openssl x509 -in GoogleCert -noout -modulus
Modulus=AAC42564448507CB736A37F...9152FD0458ECF42145
```

Copy and paste the HEX output into BC using the `ibase=16` argument to indicate the input is in Hex:

```
$ echo 'ibase=16;AAC42564448507CB736A37F...9152FD0458ECF42145' | bc
21557235071938158553153701887793754486919886530446620906710060142975\
...
80517225349695620402252397302295002436481842156355298655378997632358\
23941
```